# Copyright confusion - scientific paper

Tags: copyright, open-access

Currently, we have a discussion in our work group as to whether one may use images from WikiMedia Commons in Case Reports. I have a general understanding of what types of CC license one may use or not. However, this specific case is confusing me:

[image]

Said file has been uploaded under multiple licenses. How is this possible?

Is it correct that I can use that image for a scientific paper (provided I give proper credit) which is going to published under a "NonCommercial 4.0 International (CC BY-NC 4.0) " license?

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Background: the image is necessary for a case report in Medicine. Regrettably, it is about a plant that is not growing in winter. Thus, I need to find an alternative way of obtaining a picture of that plant.

I know there are related topics: [Can I use images from Wikipedia in my paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/168479/can-i-use-images-from-wikipedia-in-my-paper)

Yet, in this case, the image has multiple licenses.

Comment: Screenshots are not a great way to share the details of your problem

Comment: @user2705196 I am sorry - it won't repeat in the future.

Comment: If you want you can go and copy the text and then quote it here!

Answer (score 5):

> Said file has been uploaded under multiple licenses. How is this possible?

If you own something, you can license it however you want as long as you haven't agreed to some terms that prevent you from releasing it under other terms (usually referred to as an 'exclusive license'). A fairly common scenario would be releasing something under a fairly permissive license that lets others use the content for anything except commercial purposes, and then also licensing to specific users for commercial purposes for a fee.

Often journal publications occur with terms that either give the full rights to the journal and then re-license the content back to the others allowing them certain privileges, or keeping the ownership with the original authors but offering the journal an *exclusive* license that promises A) That you haven't already licensed the work for certain purposes, and B) That you can't in the future.

It seems unlikely to me that this image under either of these licenses will be useful for your purpose if you plan to submit your paper to a typical medical journal, and [I don't see compatibility with CC BY-NC 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/licensing-considerations/compatible-licenses), but I'm not going to pretend to provide legal advice on that, I'm no lawyer. It also doesn't seem like it is truly *necessary* to have an image of a plant for a case report - I'd look for something in the public domain or something you can obtain directly from the rights holder.

---

It looks like [this SE Q&A disagrees with me, suggests it's fine to use a CC-BY-SA image in a work released as CC-BY-NC, and references a dispute of this that led to a court case](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9216/using-cc-by-sa-images-in-a-cc-by-nc-sa-document). Personally, I'd still probably want clearer permission for something like this (as it seems it was still unclear enough to have a case over) or to work around the issue entirely.

Comment: Dear Bryan Krause, Thank you for your comment. It is a very difficult matter. May I ask how you judge the following issue. A paper in frontiers (which is also open access; https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpls.2021.720171/full) also used numerous CC-3.0 images. Based on my understanding and your comment, this is not legit either.

Comment: @Dr.M It doesn't look like that paper is released as CC BY-NC 4.0, but yes I think CC-BY without the SA would not be compatible. It hinges (like the Q&A I linked) on the interpretation of the courts of "remix", "transform", or "build upon". If you do those things, then you have to comply with what the licenses say about sharealike. If that's not a derivative work, then you don't. In any event, "someone else did it, too" is not a good legal argument. In practice, the vast majority of these things never see any sort of court action taken.

Answer (score 1):

IANAL, but I don't see any issue with your use of the image, provided you keep some things in mind. First, once a license is granted it can't be replaced by a more restrictive license. Both of the licenses permit what you'd like to do.

Just note, however, that your "non commercial" restriction won't apply to that image, since it already has a permissive license. The NC clause will apply to other things in your work, however, but others are still free to use the image "commercially" due to the earlier license(s).

You have to attribute the image to its source, of course. And, if you modify the image you have to adhere to the "share alike" clause which you agree to in using the image. It would be proper to put a note in the paper concerning the license on the image which both gives you rights to use it and notifies others of their rights.

---

Caveat: I can (barely) envision a situation in which that image is so essential to your larger work that you would need to apply the more permissive license to your own work. That seems unlikely, however, but would apply if the report you write could be fairly considered to be a work derived from the image.  Unlikely, but not impossible.

Comment: Thank you Buffy. Our report discusses plant intoxications of 2 potentially similar looking plants. Thus a picture is essential but hard to find on the internet.

Comment: @Dr.M Why is the picture essential? "We present here two case reports involving potentially similarly looking plants, Plant A and Plant B". Then you describe what happened to the patients. No picture needed.

Comment: Being "essential" to your paper isn't the issue. It is whether your paper constitutes a derived work. I think that is unlikely but it is a judgement call.

Comment: @Dr.M have you tried botanical books/journals as an alternative for the image source? And/or asking a research librarian?

Comment: @Lodinn Thank you for your idea! Our library is closed for personal shortage / COVID reasons these days. Luckily, I found some freely available pictures on the internet that may be used.